# Smarty is not choosing the correct templates to display

Tags: php, smarty

I was working on a website yesterday and all was well. I was porting it to use Smarty. I had one last page to change which didn't require any testing since the Smarty template file didn't really do much. I saved my work, closed everything out, and left. Earlier today, I checked the site and found that it has gone haywire. It is displaying an incorrect template for all but one page. I never changed anything with my server setup so that can't be the problem. Pages that had previously worked flawlessly no longer work. I've quintuple-checked my work and can't see what's going wrong. In order to not post every single thing I have, I will share any code of mine that you would like to take a look at. Just leave a comment, and I will make an edit. Any ideas what could be going wrong? I am using Smarty 3.1.8 and PHP 5.3.3.

[Live site](http://bama.ua.edu/~tscrompton/)

Comment: Well, visiting your link it seems everything is working? Can you clarify what is not working (perhaps paste a tpl file that is not rendering). However, my default thing to check with Smarty is the template and the cache dirs - are they writeable? Do you have the right permissions?  The only problem that I can see is that [index.css](http://bama.ua.edu/~tscrompton/annotation/browse/index.css) is a 404

Comment: It seems that it is randomly choosing different templates to display. The link I gave should point to a page with four links to the other pages. And well, the other pages should be obvious that they are incorrect given the keywords in the URL. I have the necessary permissions for all the directories and files I am using. I've tried this on three different machines and two different browsers. I am not using caching. The only template in `/st8/tscrompton/includes/Smarty-templates` is `footer.tpl`. The others are in the same directory as their corresponding PHP scripts `(index.php -> index.tpl)`.

Comment: And by random, it seems to choose one particular random template and use that one for a good while and then it will change it's mind (possibly whenever I make any changes?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mix-up is occurring because (almost) all of the templates are named the same thing. As per [this thread](http://www.smarty.net/forums/viewtopic.php?p=67250), I found that when Smarty compiles the templates, it only considers the file name, not the full path to that file. Therefor, you must specify a compile ID, which for this purpose is best to be the parent directory of the currently executing script. If you use just the `__FILE__` constant, you may end up with multiple compilations of the same template if you use multiple scripts in the same directory to display the same template. So I use `dirname(__FILE__)` for my compile ID which *should* work for everybody.