# Smarty PHP templates, mod rewrite changing URL but not page

Tags: php, caching, mod-rewrite, apache2, smarty

I've rewritten this question now as I don't think the problem is to do with the URL rewrite.

I'm building a site with PHP and Smarty and using fairly common url rewriting using apache's mod rewrite.

Locally, if I visit: **example.com/search/?q=test**, I get search results for "test". **/search** is not a real directory, it's forwarding to **search.php?q=**

When I upload, it's not working. I've enabled rewrite with `sudo a2enmod rewrite` and the url is updating, the browser shows **example.com/search/?q=test** in the address bar, doesn't throw a 404, but just serves up my index.php page instead.

I've realised the problem is probably to do with my Smarty caching. I've got a URL variable that triggers the cache to be rebuilt, *?rebuildCacheNow*.

If I go to */account*, I get the index page, but if I go to */account?rebuildCacheNow* the account page shows up.

If I then go back to the index, */*, it still shows the account page. Going to */?rebuildCacheNow* shows me the home page.

This is my main Smarty template:

```
{* Smarty *}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie6" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7 ]><html class="ie ie7" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8 ]><html class="ie ie8" lang="en"><![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html lang="en"><!--<![endif]-->

{include 'head.tpl'}

<body id="top">

{include 'header.tpl'}

<div class="content-container">
    <div class="container content">
      {include $page.content}
    </div>
</div>

{include 'footer.tpl'}

<script src="{$JQUERY_CDN}"></script>
<script src="{$BOOTSTRAP_JS_CDN}"></script>
<script src="/js/main.js"></script>
{$page.scripts}

</body>
</html>
```

Every page serves up this template, but I'm using PHP to assign `$page.content`. So the */buy* page sets `$page.content = 'buy.tpl'` and */search* sets `$page.content = 'search.tpl'`.

But it looks like the `main.tpl` is being cached - is there a better way of using 1 main outline template and embedding content templates within?

Comment: 1) Did you restart apache after enabling mod_rewrite? 2) What do your rewrite logs say?

Comment: I've restarted Apache many times, where should I look for rewrite logs?

Comment: Set RewriteLog (default is /var/log/apache2/rewrite.log) and RewriteLogLevel, then restart Apache again.  You may need RewriteLogLevel 3 to get enough information.

Comment: Do those longs help at all? It seems to be showing the error.php page for every request

Comment: It is quite possible your rule never gets used. .htaccess files from a particular directory only get read once the server has determined that what it needs to serve ought to exist in that directory, after the URL to Filename translation. If something before that leads to the server thinking that it should serve error.php, than that is what is being served. 
Since it appears you have access to the httpd.conf I would suggest you avoid putting rewrite in .htaccess files.

Comment: I've switched to using Vhost, the errors have gone from the rewrite log but the problem is still there. I think it's to do with Smarty

Comment: possible duplicate of [Smarty is not choosing the correct templates to display](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10575213/smarty-is-not-choosing-the-correct-templates-to-display)

Comment: The answer on the possible duplicate page doesn't help, also the question outlines a different problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I've worked it out. So locally I have the `rebuildCacheNow` set to go off on every page to ensure I see the changes each time - that's why I didn't notice it.

When I worked out it was to do with the caching of the `main.tpl`, checking the Smarty docs shows that I can assign a cache_id to the rendered template:

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/caching.multiple.caches.tpl

So when I render the Smarty template, I'm giving it the cache ID based on the hash of the `$page.content` variable:

```
// make cache id, based on template path
$cache_id = sha1( $page[ 'content' ] );

$smarty->display( 'main.tpl', $cache_id );
```